# How to lookup multiple items using vba and then use these values to calculate changes from a dynamic data set?

Tags: vba, lookup, userform

I am trying to write a code that looks up data based on a common ID then calculates the percent difference between the first entry and also the next entry of data. However, I have it linked to a VBA user form that inputs the data to a spreadsheet so the data base is dynamic.

Ideally, I would like to display the "% Change since first entry" and "% Change since last entry" in a text box on my user form as well as dumping in the excel table.

So for example please see the image attached;

Excel Data- Example

[image]

Say I was to enter the word "Dog" in a text box in a userform. In the text box for:

- "%Change since first entry" the display would be 60%,
- "%Change since last entry" the display would be 100%".

Ideally, I am trying to get to a point to which I can plot a graph of the trend of the percentage change over time, but I'm trying to get my head around the best way to solve this issue first.

```
Option Explicit
 Public b As String

 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim nm, v, pcf, pc As Variant, cNext As Range
 Dim ws As Worksheet, vFirst, vLast
 Dim Cell ' you had c but changed to cell as it worked for me.

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set cNext = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'next empty 
                                                                    'row

   b = TextBox1.Value ' was nm changed to be to suit what I had.

  'find the current first and last values
       For Each Cell In ws.Range("A2", cNext.Offset(-1, 0))
        If Cell.Value = b Then
        If IsEmpty(vFirst) Then vFirst = Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value 'first                                                              
                                                                'occurrence
         vLast = Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value                          'last 
                                                               ' occurrence
        End If
   Next Cell 'changed from loop to next cell

    v = TextBox2.Value
   pcf = percent(v, vFirst)
   pc = percent(v, vLast)

    'add values to sheet at next empty row
    cNext.Resize(1, 5).Value = Array(b, TextBox5.Value, v, pcf, pc)'this is 
                                                                     'cool

    TextBox3.Value = pcf
    TextBox4.Value = pc
  End Sub

'Percentage change  formula
 Function percent(x, y)

    If x And y = 0 Or x = 0 Or y = 0 Then
      percent = Format(0, "Percent")
    Else
      percent = Format(((x - y) / y), "Percent")
    End If

  End Function
  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  TextBox5 = Now
  TextBox5 = Format(TextBox5.Value, "dd mmm yyyy")
  End Sub
```

Comment: There are a numbers of ways you can do this - from a simple loop through using Find(), Match() etc.  Did you already try something?  If Yes, what happened?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your comment, I have added in the code which I have managed to get working. I assume there is probably a better way I would very much like to see it as I kinda just put this together. I know, there's a better way then to call out the Find_first_Occurrence function 3 times when the only value changing is n. If I was to plot the change in % over time what function or vba code would I call out? would I have to store the values in an array or could just get it lookup and plot the values? again thank you for your message and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will your data always be sorted by date?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little shorter.  You can skip some code if you don't add the current record to the sheet, only to go looking for it again...

```
Private Sub Cb_Click()
    Dim nm, v, pcf, pc As Variant, cNext As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, vFirst, vLast

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set cNext = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'next empty row

    nm = TextBox1.Value

    'find the current first and last values
    For Each c In ws.Range("A2", cNext.Offset(-1, 0))
        If c.Value = b Then
            If IsEmpty(vFirst) Then vFirst = c.Offset(0, 2).Value 'first occurence
            vLast = c.Offset(0, 2).Value                          'last occurence
        End If
    Loop

    v = TextBox2.Value
    pcf = percent(v, vFirst)
    pc = percent(v, vLast)

    'add values to sheet at next empty row
    cNext.Resize(1, 5).Value = Array(b, TextBox5.Value, v, pcf, pc)

    TextBox3.Value = pcf
    TextBox4.Value = pc

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I knew there was neater way to cycle through the rows of data, I just couldn't get my head around arrays, but this has helped a lot with understanding how to practically use them. This works perfect. I just had to change a few things to get to work, but it work great. Thank you so much!